# Using multiple independent Vector Spaces to represent a function

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, linear-transformations

In multiple domains its useful to transform a function from $$f(x) \Longrightarrow f(w)$$ by a change of basis.  Unfortunately, there may be a very large number of basis required to represent the function e.g. to represent the function
$$
f(x) = x 
$$
requires only a single point in polynomial space and to represent 
$$
f(x) = \sin x 
$$
requires a single point in frequency space. but representing 
$$
f(x) = x + \sin x
$$
requires activation of the entire frequency space or the entire space of polynomial functions. Is there a general approach to combining multiple vector spaces to represent a function?

Comment: "Activation of the entire frequency of the entire space of polynomial functions"? What are you talking about?

Comment: A change of basis to e^ikx of $$x + sin(x)$$ would have non-zero components for all k.  Similarly using an orthonormal polynomial basis would yield the same result.

Comment: By the way, what functional space do you consider, exactly?

Comment: In this particular case the two function spaces under consideration would be the space of sin functions or the hermite polynomials equipped with the L2 norm.  Although for any vector space consisting of a single function class a counter example could be pulled which would require an infinite set of vectors to be used.  The notion of combining vector spaces would be useful in contexts where convergence is a premium ( e.g. a computer can't evaluate an infinite vector space ).